# Libgdx can't batch timer properly

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to build a timer, but something is going wrong and i can't find out what. That's why I'm doing this question. Anyways, below is my code that's doing this so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfSYH0imDQk&feature=youtu.be&hd=1
There are 4 variables:Second4(the 4th number), Second3(the 3rd number), Minute2(the 2nd number) and Minute1(the 1st number)

```
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() -  timePassed >1000000000){
                if(timerSecond4==10){
                    timerSecond4=0;
                    if(timer%10==0 &&timerSecond3!=5)
                    timerSecond3++;
                    else if(timerSecond3==5){
                        timerSecond3=0;
                        timerSecond4=0;
                        timerMinute2++;
                        if(timerMinute2%10==0){
                            timerMinute1++;
                            timerMinute2=0;
                        }
                    }
                    timerMinutes1=checkNumberTimer(timerMinute1);
                    batch.draw(timerMinutes1,550,380);
                    timerMinutes2=checkNumberTimer(timerMinute2);
                    batch.draw(timerMinutes2,590,380);
                    timerSeconds3=checkNumberTimer(timerSecond3);
                    batch.draw(timerSeconds3,650,380);
                    timerSeconds4=checkNumberTimer(timerSecond4);
                    batch.draw(timerSeconds4,690,380);

                }
                else{
                    timerMinutes1=checkNumberTimer(timerMinute1);
                    batch.draw(timerMinutes1,550,380);
                    timerMinutes2=checkNumberTimer(timerMinute2);
                    batch.draw(timerMinutes2,590,380);
                    timerSeconds3=checkNumberTimer(timerSecond3);
                    batch.draw(timerSeconds3,650,380);
                    timerSeconds4=checkNumberTimer(timerSecond4);
                    batch.draw(timerSeconds4,690,380);
                }
                batch.draw(colons,627,387);
                timer++;
                timerSecond4++;
                timePassed();
            }

    public Texture checkNumberTimer(int t){
                Texture n=null;
                switch(t){
                case 0:n= zeroTimer;break;
                case 1:n= oneTimer;break;
                case 2:n= twoTimer;break;
                case 3:n= threeTimer;break;
                case 4:n= fourTimer;break;
                case 5:n= fiveTimer;break;
                case 6:n= sixTimer;break;
                case 7:n= sevenTimer;break;
                case 8:n= eightTimer;break;
                case 9:n= nineTimer;break;
                }
                return n;
            }


            public void timePassed() {
                timePassed=TimeUtils.nanoTime();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bah! 
I bet it's messed somewhere in your nested 'if' statements.
Wouldn't be easier just  to measure whole game time - from timer start to current time - divide it by seconds, ten-seconds, minutes and ten-minutes, and then just display it?

Somehow like:

```
long startTime;
long timePassed;

//while starting your game:
startTime=TimeUtils.millis(); 
//the difference, in milliseconds, between 
//the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. 

[...]

//and then in render loop:

timePassed=TimeUtils.millis()-startTime; 
//above line will give you time from game start, in miliseconds

timerSeconds4=(timePassed/1000)%10;     //seconds
timerSeconds3=(timePassed/10000)%10;    //ten-seconds
timerMinutes2=timePassed/60000;    //minutes
timerMinutes1=(timePassed/600000)%10;   //ten-minutes

batch.draw(timerMinutes1texture...
etc...
```

I didnt tested it, but i believe, it should work just fine :)

Plus, its lag-independent, if  something delays your loop, it will have no impact on your timer

Comment: i already solved it on my own but i'll give you thumbs up for kindness